# Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure `SP_CHADOTHERREPORTS`

When executing `SP_CHADOTHERREPORTS` from `VB.NET`. I get an error like this:

[image]

here is my code for executing `SP_CHADOTHERREPORTS` in `VB.NET`:

```
Dim subreporttype as varchar = "Report1"
Dim DatabaseFINAL as varchar = "TBLREPORT"
Dim acctcode as varchar = "TBLREPORT.acctcode"
Dim varmonth as integer = 1
Dim varyear as integer = 2011

Execute("EXECUTE SP_CHADOTHERREPORTS '" & subreporttype & "','" & DatabaseFINAL & "','" & acctcode & "'," & dt.Rows(ctr).Item("ReporttypeName").ToString & "," & varmonth & ", " & varyear & "")
```

While this one is the code in `SP_CHADOTHERREPORTS` from `SQL SERVER 2008`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CHADOTHERREPORTS]
@Subreport as varchar(100),
@TableName as varchar(100),
@AccountCode as varchar(100),
@ReportName as varchar(100),
@AcctPeriod as numeric(18,0),
@AcctYear as numeric(18,0)

AS
IF @Subreport = 'REPORT1'
BEGIN
DECLARE @Query as varchar(1000)
SET @Query = 
'UPDATE CHADotherCharges ' +
' SET Jan = ( ' +
' SELECT Jan FROM '+ @TableName +
' WHERE CHADothercharges.acctcode = '''+ @AccountCode +'' +
' AND ReportName = '+ @ReportName + 
' AND acctperiod = '+ convert(varchar(18), @AcctPeriod) +
' AND acctyear = '+ convert(varchar(18), @AcctYear) +
') ' +
'FROM Chadothercharges WHERE type IN(''+'',''SUM'',''-'')'
EXEC (@Query)
END
```

Comment: Just add `select @Query` before `EXEC (@Query)` and examine the query. Also, it's better to  use parameterised queries to prevent sql injections.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious problem is this line:

```
' WHERE CHADothercharges.acctcode = '''+ @AccountCode +'' +
-------------------------------------------------------^
```

That does nothing.  I assume you want to put in a single quote, as `''''`.

However, the real way to approach this is by using `sp_executesql` and using parameters for all the constant values in the query.  You can't use this for `@TableName`, but you can use it for the values in the `WHERE`.

Comment: `DECLARE @Query as varchar(1000)
SET @Query = 
'UPDATE CHADotherCharges ' +
' SET Jan = ( ' +
' SELECT Jan FROM '+ @TableName +
' WHERE CHADothercharges.acctcode = @acctcode' +
' AND ReportName = '+ @ReportName + 
' AND acctperiod = '+ convert(varchar(18), @AcctPeriod) +
' AND acctyear = '+ convert(varchar(18), @AcctYear) +
') ' +
'FROM Chadothercharges WHERE type IN(''+'',''SUM'',''-'')'
EXEC sp_executesql @query, '@acctcode varchar(100)', @acctcode = @AccountCode`